# Fill cell color and value depending on another cell color and value

Tags: excel

Let's consider we have A row and B.

I want cell B1 be the same color (style) as A1 with its value. I believe there is short way to do that.

How to do that?

Comment: Copy / pastespecial > formats?

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey no, I just need to fill the same value and cell color (style) instead of copypaste

Comment: @Robert are you trying to do this with VBA? There's not a formula for copying formatting and at:EvilBlueMonkey is right that Conditional formatting will work.  Maybe provide more information about your data and what values are in the cells and what conditions would cause B1 to be the same color as A1.

Comment: @Sam I just need to have two same rows. It can be A and W, for example. Just need to fill same text and ceil color both A and W instead of copy pasting. I understand it is easy, but when I type in W1 smth like "=A1", it copies text but not ceil's color (style). And I need both text and color (style)

Comment: Formulas can't copy formatting from one cell to another. Neither can conditional formatting.

Comment: @BigBen Ok, how can I access to way how to do that?

Comment: Maybe VBA as noted in the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work when you actually change the value of the given cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declaring variables.
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngDestination As Range
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngSource = Range("A1")
    Set RngDestination = Range("B1")
    
    'Checking if RngSource is within Target.
    If Not Application.Intersect(RngSource, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Coping-pasting RngSource into RngDestination.
        RngSource.Copy RngDestination
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Place it in the worksheet module. Note that it will copy the format but it won't be activated when you change the format of the source. No worksheet's event is generated when you change the format of a cell. I know no way to detect it.